# How to delete pinned points?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm working with QGIS Brighton. My project was started with an older version of the software, but I don't think that makes a difference. I have six points that were generated  by calculating the intersection of other layers that are no longer part of my project. At the time, I added a pinned label to each point. I thought that when I would delete the layers that created the intersections that the labeled points would also disappear. This didn't happen and I can't seem to delete the pins no matter what I do since they don't exist on a layer that is in the project.

I'm attaching a picture of the pinned point (circled in blue).[image: pinned.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Text Annotation** tool [image] to select the annotations ("pinned points") and use the Delete key to remove them.